# Error while installing opencv-contrib-python

Tags: linux, python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to install opencv-contrib -python in python 3 and opencv version is 3.3.0 
using the code :
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python

but i am getting a error:
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-contrib-python3 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for opencv-contrib-python

If anyone can help !!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by removing the current version of `opencv` using

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
```

and follow this with

```
pip install opencv-python==4.1.0.25 opencv-contrib-python==4.1.0.25
```

or replace with your desired version of `opencv` and `opencv-contrib`. I believe they need to be the same for this to work properly.